# problem installing webrick / mogrel or any other server for Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, mongrel, webrick

I have tried various installation methods for deploying a WEBrick and mongrel from the terminal.  When I enter the rails server command I get the following:

```
Toran1$ rails server
/Users/Toran1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require': dlopen(/Users/Toran1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/Toran1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/Toran1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    from /Users/Toran1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Toran1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/Toran1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/Toran1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Users/Toran1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Toran1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Users/Toran1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/Toran1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
    from /Users/Toran1/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Toran1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from /Users/Toran1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/Toran1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /Users/Toran1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I have installed the gem both locally and at the root level, and I also have navigated to the application folder before issuing the command.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Webrick will install automatically if you install rails in a correct manner.

Try this link
[Here](http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2010/09/01/How-to-install-Rails-3.0-and-Ruby-1.9.2-on-Ubuntu)

And if you don't want to install rails again, try to install server using gem command

## Dont forget to include the gems in Gemfile and to run "bundle install"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails < 3.1 you need to use version ~> 0.2.7 of the mysql2 gem

Checkout the documentation and search for active record: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2

I'm not sure if that will help solve this problem directly, but it may solve others that you may encounter.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your bundler, maybe of any-one of the older gem is conflicting with latest one, this type of issues arises.

```
gem install bundler
```

and then `bundler install`

If you find again error, then delete GEM.lock file, then run

```
bundler install
```

This may resolve the issue.

Comment: I tried this method but constantly get "-bash: bundler: command not found